# Why pointcut.matches(String.class) returns "true"

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I am new to spring AOP and I write a small test
of aspectJ AOP pointcut,

```
public void test1() {

    AspectJExpressionPointcut pointcut = new AspectJExpressionPointcut();
    pointcut.setExpression("execution(public * java.util.*.*(..))");

    System.out.println(pointcut.matches(String.class)) ;
}
```

I expect it will print out "false", because String.class is not include in java.util package.
but actually it gives me the "true", 
What mistake I made?

version: spring 3.0

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This pointcut is looking for **executions of methods** from the `java.util` package and sub-packages, of which there are several in the `String` class. e.g. the source of [`String.replaceFirst(String, String)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst%28java.lang.String%2C%20java.lang.String%29) looks as follows (comments inserted by me):

```
public String replaceFirst(String regex, String replacement) {
return 
        /* java.util.regex.Pattern */ Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(this)
        /* java.util.regex.Matcher */ .replaceFirst(replacement);
}
```

So the match is correct.